# NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined -- CIFAR-10を使ったクラスわけでエラー, Python2.7.12

Tags: python, 深層学習, 機械学習

以下のリンクにあるCIFAR-10(ラベル付されたサイズが32x32のカラー画像8000万枚のデータセット)を読み取り、Nearest Neighbor Classifierによりクラス分けしその精度を%で出力させたいのですが以下のエラー出てしまいました。問題は58行目のxrangeにあるようですが解決方法がみつからず、何かアドバイス頂けると幸いです。

以下データ元:
http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html

以下コードです:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import os

def unpickle(file):
    fo = open(file, 'rb')
    u = pickle._Unpickler(fo)
    u.encoding = 'latin1'
    dict = u.load()
    fo.close()
    return dict

def conv_data2image(data):
    return np.rollaxis(data.reshape((3,32,32)),0,3)

def get_cifar10(folder):
    tr_data = np.empty((0,32*32*3))
    tr_labels = np.empty(1)
    '''
    32x32x3
    '''
    for i in range(1,6):
        fname = os.path.join(folder, "%s%d" % ("data_batch_", i))
        data_dict = unpickle(fname)
        if i == 1:
            tr_data = data_dict['data']
            tr_labels = data_dict['labels']
        else:
            tr_data = np.vstack((tr_data, data_dict['data']))
            tr_labels = np.hstack((tr_labels, data_dict['labels']))

    data_dict = unpickle(os.path.join(folder, 'test_batch'))
    te_data = data_dict['data']
    te_labels = np.array(data_dict['labels'])

    bm = unpickle(os.path.join(folder, 'batches.meta'))
    label_names = bm['label_names']
    return tr_data, tr_labels, te_data, te_labels, label_names


class NearestNeighbor(object):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def train(self, X, y):
    """ X is N x D where each row is an example. Y is 1-dimension of size N """
    # the nearest neighbor classifier simply remembers all the training data
    self.Xtr = X
    self.ytr = y

  def predict(self, X):
    """ X is N x D where each row is an example we wish to predict label for """
    num_test = X.shape[0]
    # lets make sure that the output type matches the input type
    Ypred = np.zeros(num_test, dtype = self.ytr.dtype)

    # loop over all test rows
    for i in xrange(num_test):
      # find the nearest training image to the i'th test image
      # using the L1 distance (sum of absolute value differences)
      distances = np.sum(np.abs(self.Xtr - X[i,:]), axis = 1)
      min_index = np.argmin(distances) # get the index with smallest distance
      Ypred[i] = self.ytr[min_index] # predict the label of the nearest example

    return Ypred

if __name__ == '__main__':
    datapath = "./data/cifar-10-batches-py"

    tr_data10, tr_labels10, te_data10, te_labels10, label_names10 = get_cifar10(datapath)
    Xtr, Ytr, Xte, Yte, label_names10 = get_cifar10(datapath)
    Xtr_rows = Xtr.reshape(Xtr.shape[0], 32 * 32 * 3)
    Xte_rows = Xte.reshape(Xte.shape[0], 32 * 32 * 3)
    nn = NearestNeighbor()  # create a Nearest Neighbor classifier class
    nn.train(Xtr_rows, Ytr)  # train the classifier on the training images and labels
    Yte_predict = nn.predict(Xte_rows)  # predict labels on the test images
    # and now print the classification accuracy, which is the average number
    # of examples that are correctly predicted (i.e. label matches)
    print(Yte_predict)
```

以下エラー

> "C:\…\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe"
>   "C:/…/PycharmProjects/Convolutional Neural
>   Networks for Visual Recognition/input_cifar.py" 
>   Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "C:/…/PycharmProjects/Convolutional Neural Networks for Visual
>   Recognition/input_cifar.py", line 76, in 
>       Yte_predict = nn.predict(Xte_rows)  # predict labels on the test images   File "C:/Users/Naoki Ishibashi/PycharmProjects/Convolutional
>   Neural Networks for Visual Recognition/input_cifar.py", line 58, in
>   predict
>       for i in xrange(num_test): NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xrange()`は Python2.x 系のメソッドです。Python3.x 系では `range()` を使います。

実行している`python`のパスを見る限り、今回動かしているものは Python3.5 のように見えます。

同じ環境に Python2.x 系と Python3.x 系が同時に入っている場合は、どちらが実行されるのか分かりやすくするためにコマンド名で区別したり(`python2`, `python3`)、エラーが起こったときはまずバージョンを疑ったり (`python --version`) などすると良いと思います。

また、エラーが起こったときはそのエラー名でググるのも良い戦略です。今回の場合、

> NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined

でググると「バージョンが違います」という回答が載ったページがいくつか出てきます。

Comment: ご回答頂きありがとうございます。ご指摘頂いた通りバージョンの問題でした。2.7に統一することでエラー解消されました！